# how can I convert my word list to usable type for removing list of stopwords

Tags: python, list, nltk

I converted words to their roots and build a corpus which includes 100k texts but format of each is inappropriate for removing stop words

I tried ' '.join function but it added ' ' for each letter and '[' and ']'

```
corr=[]
pattern = r'\w*' 
for a in range (0,113340):
   rew = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: str(my_dictionary.get(m.group(0), 
         m.group(0))), te.CUST_TXT[a])
   corr.append(rew)
```

Above I converted words to root and results are below:

```
print(corr[1111])
['buyur'] ['ben'] ['ben'] ['evet'] ['buyur'] ['evet'] ['aynı']

a=corr[1111]
for aa in a:
   print(aa.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",''))
b
u
y
u
r

print(' '.join(corr[1111]))  
[ ' b u y u r ' ]   [ ' b e n ' ]
```

I have sl (list of stopwords) and want to remove those words from each text of corr

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do, but to me it seems like you are trying to use ''.join() (empty string, not ' ').

Comment: at the end  I want to have texts(which are in corr) which doesnt have stopwords(which are in list) I applied `[word for word in  te.CUST_TXT[1] if not word in list]`but python compare every letter to stop words

Comment: what's in `te.CUST_TXT[1]`?

Comment: `type(te.CUST_TXT[1] )  <class 'str'>   type(te_2.CUST_TXT)  =   <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>  type(te)  =<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> ` 
 it is a sentence like ' have a nice day sir '

Comment: since `te.CUST_TXT[1]` is a string, `[word for word in te.CUST_TXT[1]]` will be an array of chars. I think what you want to do is `[word for word in te.CUST_TXT]` to read all the words in the sentence.

Comment: I found it, below what I want ,thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it

```
`for a in range(0,113340):
    corr[a] = str(corr2[a]).replace("['","").replace("']","")
    b=str(corr[a]).split(' ')
    b=[word for word in b if not word in sl ]
    b=' '.join(b)
    corr[a]=b`
```

that gives me words of each texts in corr not letters , space or special characters